# Event is not triggered after adding new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML list:

```
<ul>
```

contains initial items of:

```
<li>
```

I have added new items dynamically to that list. Old items are responding very well , but the new ones cannot be triggered for the same event.

I am using (.on) event as per JQuery documentation to trigger the current and future elements. But still not responding.

```
$(".favorite-btn").on("click",function(){
    alert("Yes!");              
 });
```

Could you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for dynamically added DOM elements as shown below :-

```
$(document.body).on("click",".favorite-btn",function(){
    alert("Yes!");              
});
```

OR

```
$("ul#id").on("click",".favorite-btn",function(){
    alert("Yes!");              
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added elements:

```
$("ul").on("click",'.favorite-btn',function(){
 alert("Yes!");              
});
```